# Plot total number of users by date joined

Tags: knime

Is there any function or node which will add the number of elements in a set chronologically?

I would like to create a simple line graph of "total number of users" over time, but what I have is "user_email" (unique) and "date_created" for the date the user joined.

What is the easiest way to sum the number of users at any given time from their creation date and plot it in a graph according to time?

I tried searching for this, but didn't find anything related.  New to KNIME.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `user_email` only contains unique values, you can sort the table by `date_created` (if it isn't already sorted) then use a **Counter Generation** node to add a column containing a counter value.

For a more general solution, if you want to count the cumulative total of unique values in a table column, you can use this sequence:

- **GroupBy** configured to group by the column whose unique values you want to count and to aggregate on the column you want to plot this against - for example, your timestamp column, probably with either the `First` or `Last` aggregation method
- **Sorter** to sort on the aggregation column from GroupBy
- then **Moving Aggregation** with the `Cumulative computation` box checked, and configured to aggregate on `Count` of the grouped column from GroupBy.